# Word separator application

Tags: c#

This application is supposed to take a string written is pascal case:

`HelloHowAreYou?`

and separate the words to form a sentence, keeping only the first letter capitalized:

`Hello how are you?`

As of right now, this code works only when each word stars with a different letter. The example sentence `HelloHowAreYou` comes out as `hellohow are you?`

Why is it doing this?

```
    private void btnSeparate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the sentence from the text box
        string sentence = txtWords.Text;
        int upperCase; // to hold the index of an uppercase letter

        foreach (char up in sentence)
        {

            if (char.IsUpper(up))
            {

                // Find the index of the uppercase letter
                upperCase = sentence.IndexOf(up);

                // Insert a space at the appropriate index
                sentence = sentence.Insert(upperCase, " ");
            }
        }
        // Make all the letters lowercase
        sentence = sentence.ToLower();
        // Capitalize the first letter of the sentence.
        sentence = sentence[1].ToString().ToUpper() + sentence.Substring(2);

        // Display the separeted words
        lblSeparatedWords.Text = sentence;

    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `IndexOf` (F9) and see what happens as you iterate through the string character by character.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you:

```
var test = "HelloHowAreYou";
var final = "";
bool firstCharacterCheckIsDone = false;
foreach (char c in test)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(c))
    {
        if (test.IndexOf(c) == 0 && !firstCharacterCheckIsDone)
        {
            final += " " + c.ToString();
            firstCharacterCheckIsDone = true;
        }
        else
            final += " " + c.ToString().ToLower();
    }
    else
        final += c.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(final.Trim());
```

Output:

```
Hello how are you
```

Check on [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RxrDhT)

---

As in your example `H` is being repeated in `Hello` & `How` you are not getting the output you desire.

You can make a method out of my above solution:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(FinalOutput("HelloHowAreYou?"));  
}

static string FinalOutput(string test)
{
    var final = "";
    bool firstCharacterCheckIsDone = false;
    foreach (char c in test)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(c))
        {
            if (test.IndexOf(c) == 0 && !firstCharacterCheckIsDone)
            {
                final += " " + c.ToString();

                //This here will make sure only first character is in Upper case
                //doesn't matter if the same character is being repeated elsewhere
                firstCharacterCheckIsDone = true; 
            }
            else
                final += " " + c.ToString().ToLower();
        }
        else
            final += c.ToString();
    }

    return final.Trim();
}
```

Output:

```
Hello how are you?
```

Check on [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RRYVoc)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your original version had problems with identical letters is that you used `IndexOf`. That method only ever return the first index of the letter, so if you have more than one word that starts with the same letter, your version will only change the first occurrence.

Here is another option, using a string builder:

```
string SeparateToWords(string pascalSentence)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pascalSentence))
    {
        return pascalSencentce;
    }
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    // note I'm starting from 1 not from 0 here
    for(var i = 1; i < pascalSentence.Length; i++)
    {
        if(char.IsUpper(pascalSentence[i]))
        {
            sb.Append(" ").Append(pascalSentence[i].ToString().ToLower());
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(pascalSentence[i]);
        }
    }
    sb.Insert(0, pascalSentence[0]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[Live demo or rextester](http://rextester.com/AKC54178)